# Pointers in Dev C++ vs Visual Studio

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, pointers, visual-c++

I have coded a program that gets the information of employees of a company, when I run it in Dec C++, it does run without any errors, but when I run it in Visual Studio, it returns the following error :

```
Error   C4703   potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'data' used
```

and VS asks me to rewrite the pointer like this :

```
employ *data{};
```

instaed of : `employ *data;`

Can anyone please explain why does it happen? and What this `{}` means here? Is it a thing of C++ or VS?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct employ {
    long int emp_num;
    string fn;
    string ln;
    int work_days;
    long int payday;
};

int main()
{
    int n=0;
    employ *data;
    int act;

    do {

        cout << "___________________________________________________________________________________________________________";
        cout << "\n\n\t\tWelcome to the EMPLOTASK!";
        cout << "\n\t\tFor doing any of the commands, enter number of that command.";
        cout << "\n\t\t_______________________________________________________________";
        cout << "\n\n\t\t\    ADD & EDIT : ";
        cout << "\n\t\t[1] Add new employees.";
        cout << "\n\t\t[2] Edit an existing employee.";
        cout << "\n\t\t[3] Delete an existing employee.";
        cout << "\n\t\t[4] Print list of all employees.";
        cout << "\n\t\t_______________________________________________________________";
        cout << "\n\n\t\t\    ACTIONS : ";
        cout << "\n\t\t[5] Sort based on their salary.";
        cout << "\n\t\t[6] Search for an emplyee.";
        cout << "\n\t\t[7] Calculate the average salary.";
        cout << "\n\t\t[8] Show maximum and minimum sallary.";

        cout << "\n\n\t\tWhat do you want to do?";
        cin >> act;

        if (act > 8)
            cout << "Invalid request!" << endl;

        switch (act)
        {
        case 1: {
            cout << "\n\t\t_______________________________________________________________";
            cout << "\n\n\t\t\'ADD NEW EMPLOYEES\'";
            cout << "\n\t\tEnter number of the employees : ";
            cin >> n;
            data = new employ[n];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                cout << "\n\t\t========== Employee number " << i + 1 << " ==========";
                cout << "\n\t\tFirst name : ";
                cin >> data[i].fn;
                cout << "\t\tLast name : ";
                cin >> data[i].ln;
                cout << "\t\tEmployee's number : ";
                cin >> data[i].emp_num;
                cout << "\t\tDays of work : ";
                cin >> data[i].work_days;
                cout << "\t\tDaily rate : ";
                cin >> data[i].payday;
            }
            cout << "\n\t\t=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=";
            cout << "\n\t\tOperatuon's done successfully! =)";
            cout << "\n\t\t=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=" << endl;
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            cout << "\n\t\t_______________________________________________________________";
            cout << "\n\n\t\t\'EDIT AN EMPLOYEE\'";
            cout << "\n\t\tEnter the employee number : ";
            int em_num;
            cin >> em_num;
            int yes = 0;

            if (n == 0)
            {
                cout << "There's no employee!";
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (em_num == data[i].emp_num)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {
                        cout << "\n\t\t========== Edit Employee number " << i + 1 << " ==========";
                        cout << "\n\t\tFirst name : ";
                        cin >> data[i].fn;
                        cout << "\t\tLast name : ";
                        cin >> data[i].ln;
                        cout << "\t\tEmployee's number : ";
                        cin >> data[i].emp_num;
                        cout << "\t\tDays of work : ";
                        cin >> data[i].work_days;
                        cout << "\t\tDaily rate : ";
                        cin >> data[i].payday;
                        yes++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (yes == 0)
            {
                cout << "The entered employee number is invalid.";
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
        }
    } while (act != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The Dev-C++ environment is old and unmaintained. The compiler that comes with it is equally old and unmaintained. The more up-to-date VS compiler is correct that `data` can be used uninitialized: What happens if you select `2` before `1`?

Comment: And with `employ *data{};` you [*value initialize*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) the pointer `data`. It's equivalent to `employ *data = nullptr;`. And even here you still have the problem of possibly using the null-pointer `data` before you make it point somewhere valid.

Comment: Tip: Use `std::vector<employ>`. Forget `new[]`. It's not worth the fuss.

Comment: ...but an access to a `nullptr` is usually easier to detect and fix than an access to an uninitialized pointer which may have an arbitrary value ("valid" addresses included) and hence result in weird behavior.

Comment: @tadman Thank you so much, but I'm a beginner in C++, hadn't learned "vector" yet.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat and Some Programmer Dude, thank you so much, I got it.

Comment: Embarcadero adopted Dev-C++ and [maintains a modern branch](https://github.com/Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp). If you like the feel of the tool, download and update. It's worth your time to explore other tools, though. You can't find tools you like better if you don't experiment a little from time to time.

Comment: @user4581301 I appreciate your advice, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding `{}`: uniform initialization(C++11). It enables you to initialize everything in the same way. It also provides better safety guarantees when it comes to narrowing conversions.

The following code shows some examples.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Point
{
    Point(float x, float y) : m_x{ x }, m_y{ y } {}
    float m_x;
    float m_y;
};

int main()
{
    int a{ 0 }; // same as a{}
    int b{ 1 };
    // int c{ 2.0 }; // at least warning, often error
    double d{ 3.0 };
    char* pc{nullptr}; // same as pc{}
    std::string s{ "C++" };
    std::vector<int> vi{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    Point p1{ 3.0f, 4.0f };
}
```